# Show the existence (or not) of a limit cycle.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I need to the existence, or not, of limit cycles of the following ODE system:

$$
\dot{x}(\phi) =- y(\phi) + \frac{L x(\phi)}{(x(\phi)^{2} + y(\phi)^{2})^{2}} \,\, ,
$$

$$
\dot{y}(\phi) = x(\phi) + \frac{L y(\phi)}{(x(\phi)^{2} + y(\phi)^{2})^{2}} \,\, ,
$$

with $L \in \mathbb{R}$.
I would like to prove this using the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem or Bendixson criterion, how could I do that? (My guess I that there is one in $r = 3$.)

Comment: Does equation for $x$ really have $-y$ term?

Comment: @JohnB I've fixed the question and, yes, there is a $-y$ term in the system.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of limit cycles in the system

$$\dot{x}(\phi) =- y(\phi) + \frac{L x(\phi)}{(x(\phi)^{2} + y(\phi)^{2})^{2}} \,\, ,$$
$$\dot{y}(\phi) = x(\phi) + \frac{L y(\phi)}{(x(\phi)^{2} + y(\phi)^{2})^{2}} \,\, ,$$

depends on $L$.

Transfer the system to polar coordinate by:
$$ x=rcos(\theta) ,\text { and  } y=rsin(\theta) $$

Note that $$r^2 = x^2 + y^2  \implies  r'=  \frac {xx' +yy'}{r}$$

Upon simplification we come up with $$ r' = \frac {L}{(x^2 + y^2 )^{3/2}}$$

We also have $$ \theta ' =1$$

If $L>0$, $r$ is an increasing function which implies there in no limit cycle in this system.

If $L=0$, then every orbit is a periodic  orbit.

If $ L<0$, then $r$ is a decreasing function and there is no loop.

Comment: @HerrSchrödinger Thanks for the comment but I just checked it again and I had the same result as before  $ r' = L/r^3 $

Comment: but that's not what you get in your answer, what you have there is $r' = L/\sqrt{r^{3}}$.

Comment: @HerrSchrödinger    I have $r' = \frac {L}{(x^2 + y^2 )^{3/2}} =\frac {L}{r^3}$, note that $r=\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$